# Why does addEventListener accumulate in useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs

*Functionality: entering text into input, creating a list by pressing enter.*

https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-tereshkova-96pf3?file=/src/App.js

I have two addEventListeners. One is outside of any hooks, the other in useEffect.

1. What is the logic behind the EventListener outside the hooks? Why does it behave so?
2. Why is the number of clicks doubled when I click on a list item?
3. What feature does addEventListener have that causes it to be accumulated in the useEffect hook and need to be cleaned up? *Why does console.log (), for example, not accumulating?*

Answer (score 0):

so your first of all, think of your React components as functions that are called over and over again on each render.

So in your case your first eventListener registered outside of useEffect
`document.addEventListener("click", () => console.log("foo"));`

this is called every time your component is rendered => in other words, every time your component rerenders new event listener is registered. In your case this happens in this order

1. User types 1 letter to input box
2. setTodoTitle is called with new value => this causes react to update your components
3. new event listener is registered because of rerender

Your second case is a little bit different, cuz you register your event listener in `useEffect`. Function passed (first param) to useEffect is called only when some variable from dependency array (second param) changes. So in your case `useEffect` is called only when `todos` change => after you add new todo on Enter click. You correctly use cleanup function (return {...}) in useEffect. `React performs the cleanup when the component unmounts. ... This is why React also cleans up effects from the previous render before running the effects next time` [[react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1)]

1. component mounts for first time
2. useEffect is called, because todos didn't exist before and now its set to []
3. you add new todo
4. useEffect triggers again, because `todos` changed

Comment: So let us comment tht eventListener outside hooks. Why is the number of clicks doubled when I click on a list item? Truly I've found an answer. If we console.log the target element we will see that there are two elements at one time: span and input. Agree?